# Code is not updating in Windows

Tags: c, windows, printing, compiler-construction, build

I am running a C program using DEVC++ and CodeBlocks in Windows and the code is not updating.
I just added a single printf message and it is not shown in the output.
I tried clean,rebuild,recompile, everything.

Please tell me what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a newline to your printf. Sometimes (with certain compilers), the output isn't flushed to screen until a newline is printed.

```
printf( "\n" );
```